# Filling a rectangle with 0/1 (constraints on columns/lines sums)

Tags: combinatorics, rectangles

Let's consider a $n \times m$ rectangle wich has to be filled in by $0$s and $1$s. The sum of the values contained in each colum/line is known. Here is an example:

[image]

This is a solution:

[image]

Does someone know if this problem has a name (it looks like [magic square](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_square))? I'm especially interested in the uniqueness (up to permutation of the columns) of the solution (if it exists): are there conditions that can enforce it?

Comment: Solutions are not unique.

Comment: yes, I know it's not the case in general. But it could be true if the rectangle has few enough columns for instance (for only 1 column it's ok), and if we know other sums (e.g. the sum of the top left 2*2 square is 4)

Answer (score 1):

Essentially this is the [Discrete Tomography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_tomography) problem.

The problem in general is hard. Yan Gerard has proved that the problem of rearranging the  known integer entries of a matrix to satisfy known sums of rows and columns is a NP-hard problem.

I don't know if it is easier of $\{0,1\}$.